# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined || Errors getting a single document from Firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I've lost all hope, as nothing seems to make sens (to me) at this stage anymore. I'm all good getting a collection of items, and doing what needs be done with it. But when fecthing a single Document, I'm getting all kind of troubles. Been trying to add / remove .data() in between the properies / end of the variables, using the function in test.vue && in the useProfiles TypeScript... and nothing seems to work. I'm either getting "undefined" or with an inability to access properties, of the object itself is not ready to be called.

I've also [dug back into the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/36740fb2c39383621c0c0a948236e9eab8a71516/snippets/firestore-next/test-firestore/get_custom_object.js#L8-L19) and used those samples, to no avail...

[image]

I've three files:

useProfile.ts

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useUserSession } from "/@src/stores/userSession";
import { Profile } from "/@src/types/profile";

import {
    getFirestore,
    onSnapshot,
    doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
  
const db = getFirestore();
const userSession = useUserSession();
const uid = userSession.uid

export const profile = ref<Profile>();

export const getProfile = async (id) => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "profiles", id), (profile) => {
        console.log("Profile Retrieved Successfully : ", profile.id, " => ", profile.data());
        profile.value = profile
    });
}

getProfile(uid);
```

profile.ts

```
export type Profile = {
  images: {
    avatar: string;
  },
  personal: {
    nameFirst: string;
    nameLast: string;
  },
  professional : {
    cluster: string;
  },
}
```

test.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { useViaPlaceholderError } from '/@src/composable/useViaPlaceholderError'
import { profile } from "/@src/composable/useProfiles";

</script>

<template>
  <div class="column is-one-fifth" >
    <img
        class="project-avatar"
        :src="profile.images.picture"
        alt=""
        @error.once="(event) => useViaPlaceholderError(event, '150x150')"
      />
      <h3>{{ profile.personal.nameFirst }} {{ profile.personal.nameLast }}</h3>
      <p>{{ profile.professional.cluster }}</p>
      <progress class="progress is-primary is-tiny" value="31" max="100">
        31%
      </progress>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Even after dumping everything into a simple Vue file, enclosing it with a "onMounted", I'm still getting undefined when trying to access a nested property of a single document.

Answer (score 0):

Even after stepping away from using multiple files and making my life (in the future) easier, and just dumping everything straight into a very simple vue file/component, I'm still getting undefined on the "myProfile" properties...

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref , onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useUserSession } from "/@src/stores/userSession";
import { Profile } from "/@src/types/profile";

import {
    getFirestore,
    onSnapshot,
    collection,
    doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
  
const db = getFirestore();
const userSession = useUserSession();
const userId = userSession.uid

const myProfile = ref({} as Profile);
const profiles = ref([]);
const profilesCollectionRef = collection(db, "profiles");

onMounted(() => {
 
    onSnapshot(profilesCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
        const profilesHolder = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const profile = {
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
            }
            profilesHolder.push(profile);
            console.log(profile);
        });
        
        profiles.value = profilesHolder;
    });

    onSnapshot(doc(db, "profiles", userId), (doc) => {
        const newProfile = {
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
        }
        myProfile.value = newProfile as Profile;
    });
    
})

</script>

<template>
    <LandingLayout theme="light">
        <div v-for="profile in profiles" class="mb-5">
            <a>{{profile.personal.nameFirst}}</a>
            <br>
            <a>{{profile.images.avatar}}</a>
        </div>

        <a>{{myProfile.personal.nameFirst}}</a>
    </LandingLayout>
</template>
```

[image]